# Where to store cross referenced SQL values?

Tags: sql, join

I'm building a movie database with two tables, one containing movie names and the other containing actor names. How do I cross reference the data?

For example, should entries in the movie names table contain a list of actors for each movie, or should entries in the actor names table contain a list of movies for actor?

Comment: Neither. Do not store lists. It only leads to headaches. See Michael's response for a good normalized design :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need an additional table which links the two, and contains at least the movie id and actor id as its columns.  Assuming your `Actors` table has `actor_id` as its primary key, and `Movies` has `movie_id` as its primary key.  This table could also include information about the actor specific to that movie, for example, the character's name or other character-related info.

```
CREATE TABLE actors_in_movies (
  /* Use whatever auto increment keyword is needed for your RDBMS */
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY <auto increment>,
  actor_id INT,
  movie_id INT,
  character_name VARCHAR(),
  other_character_info VARCHAR(),
  character_best_quote TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY (actor_id) REFERENCES actors (actor_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES actors (movies_id)
);
```

#### To query all the movies an actor appears in,

use something to the effect of:

```
SELECT
  actors.*,
  movies.name
FROM
  actors 
  JOIN actors_in_movies ON actors.actor_id = actors_in_movies.actor_id
  JOIN movies ON movies.movie_id = actors_in_movies.movie_id
WHERE actors.actor_id = <some actor id>
```

#### To query all the actors in a particular movie,

use something to the effect of:

```
SELECT
  actors.*
FROM
  actors 
  JOIN actors_in_movies ON actors.actor_id = actors_in_movies.actor_id
  JOIN movies ON movies.movie_id = actors_in_movies.movie_id
WHERE movies.movie_id = <some movie id>
```

To add an actor to a movie, insert a row into your `actors_in_movies` table:

```
INSERT INTO actors_in_movies (actor_id, movie_id) VALUES (..., ...);
```

Comment: I might put a surrogate key on the relation table for this scenario, since it's possible he'd want multiple entries per actor per movie.  Think of Eddie Murphy where he plays like 4 characters in the same film.

Comment: I can't over state how impressed I am. Ask question, make toast, question answered more thoroughly than I imagined possible. Thankyou!

Comment: @Kratos Welcome to Stack Overflow - usually you won't even have time to make toast :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a cross table!  Have a table which has only two columns: movieID, actorID.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a third table, one called `ActorInMovie`. This table should have 2 columns. `ActorID, MovieID`.

This way, you'll be able to have a many to many rel.